# ASP Website FileSystemObject.CreateFolder Permission Denied Error

Tags: javascript, iis, authentication

I've got an ASP website running on IIS 7.0. The app pool is classic, .NET 2.0. The identity of the process is the NetworkService.

The problem I've got is that on the server, I have some Javascript that (used to work) would create an ActiveX object of Scripting.FileSystemObject and try to create a folder in a virtual directory that happened to be on a shared folder in a remote machine.

I get a "permission denied" exception.

The virtual folder has a user account associated with it that's on our domain so it should be able access the shared folder no problem. When I do the "test connection" in IIS, it tells me so. I've tried giving it a full admin account just to see if it would work, but it doesn't. I even tried changing the application pool identity to a domain account but that didn't work either.

I've run out of ideas regarding what to try. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated,

mj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the stupid thing out.

Apparently, I had to set the authentication settings in IIS7 to a user on my domain. I thought that just setting up the account under the virtual directory set up was enough but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

I want to complement this question with information that newer versions of IIS uses the Application Pool user (default: IIS APPPOOL to find it search for IIS APPPOOL\ ) to control the folder permissions. So if you get a permission denied creating folder or trying to upload file, adding write permissions to the folder for user IIS AppPool user might work.